# Sticky session with nginx base on the query string

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

we are using socket.io for connecting client to service in the cloude (http requests).
in the cloude we will have sevral servers and we need stickness that is **not** base on coockie.
we prefer that it will be based on parameter we get in the query string.

is it possible not on nginx plus?

Comment: Not a query string but an alternative without cookies. You can load-balance by an IP hash, which means that requests coming from the same IP being forwarded to the same server (see [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html#nginx_load_balancing_with_ip_hash) ). The downside is that load-balancing might be unequal.

Comment: And there is also a [generic hash](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#hash) load-balancing method, which allows you to use a variable (like a query string) with the same downside.